# DocuSign.eSign.dll parameter not valid

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am currently working on a project that requires me to send and receive contracts via DocuSign and then upload the completed contracts to a web service.
I have completed the sending and receiving parts of the development but am unable to add a web service reference (I am fairly new at using web services) due to the following error:

The Connect Services component 'Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider' failed: (HRESULT:0x80070057) The specified parameter value 'DocuSign.eSign.dll' is not valid. Parameter Name: 'packageName'

How do I go about resolving this issue? Where is a good place to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign.eSign.dll is not a web service but a NuGet package.
You add it to your project just like you would add other DLL files from Microsoft or third party.
See step-by-step in our [guide on using the DocuSign eSignature SDK](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/c-sharp/setup-and-configuration/).

Or, an easier approach would be to use our [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) that sets it all for you automatically.

Comment: I have successfully installed the DocuSign NuGet package but it is blocking me from adding a WCF web reference with the error: The Connect Services component 'Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider' failed: (HRESULT:0x80070057) The specified parameter value 'DocuSign.eSign.dll' is not valid. Parameter Name: 'packageName'

Comment: What is the reason you need WCF?

Comment: After the contract has been signed in DocuSign I retrieve it from the DocuSign envelope API I then need to upload it to a WCF web reference to copy it to another server. But when I attempt to add the WCF Web Reference to the c# project I get the above error message.

Comment: OK, so the issue is WCF related. Im not sure why WCF is trying to load DocuSign.eSign.dll, but this should not be configured as a service for WCF. 
You may want to have 2 projects, one with WCF and one with DocuSign and communicate between them without loading the other DLL.

Comment: I have split the project into 2 different project as you suggested and it functions now. I will mark the question as answered thank you for the help.